# Perl, inline function for empty xml tag compression using DOM parser

Tags: xml, perl, dom, syntax

I'm fairly new to perl and I'm using a [perl DOM parser](http://search.cpan.org/~tjmather/XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM.pm) and there is an example of how to handle tag compression with empty elements that gives an example here:

```
 XML::DOM::setTagCompression (\&my_tag_compression);

 sub my_tag_compression
 {
    my ($tag, $elem) = @_;

    # Print empty br, hr and img tags like this: <br />
    return 2 if $tag =~ /^(br|hr|img)$/;

    # Print other empty tags like this: <empty></empty>
    return 1;
 }
```

I understand why this is done, but I don't need anything this sophisticated, since I just want my function to return 1 all of the time.  So my "my_tag_compression" sub would be written like...

```
 XML::DOM::setTagCompression (\&my_tag_compression);

 sub my_tag_compression
 {
    return 1;
 }
```

How would I, or is it possible, to do the above in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write:

```
XML::DOM::setTagCompression( sub { 1; } );
```